# How to loop in oozie using sub-workflow?

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

It has been [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684647/handling-loops-in-oozie-workflow?answertab=votes#tab-top) that one could use the oozie-subworkflow to execute an action multiple times. I can't figure out how to actually do it.

Let's say I need to invoke a map-reduce action *N* times.  Let's say I encapsulate the map-reduce action in a sub-workflow.  I can manually invoke the sub-workflow *N* times by having *N* actions in my oozie-workflow (as outlined in this [approach](https://github.com/rkanter/oozie-subwf-repeat-example)).  But *N* needs to be dynamic.  So:

- How do I decrease the loop-counter to ensure that I don't execute the sub-workflow more than *N* times.
- Can I execute the *N* sub-workflows in parallel.

I have thought of 2 approaches:

**Approach 1:**
I was thinking of having a java action that decreases a counter, capture its arguments and use that as a way to keep track of the loop-counter.  If loop-counter is not zero invoke the subworkflow.  However, how could I call that java action multiple-times...a catch-22?

**Approach 2:**
Another approach would be to ditch the sub-workflow idea and encapsulate the map-reduce (mapRed-workflow.xml) job in a normal workflow, then implement a java action that executes the oozie-workflow (mapRed-workflow.xml) *N* times.  I could even do this in parallel, wait for all the jobs to finish then return to the main workflow.  My main concern with this approach is lack of reliability.  What would happen if the java action dies half-way through?  For example it would schedule *N/2* oozie jobs then die (for some reason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After internal discussion we decided to use velocity to produce workflow.  So instead of iterating *N* times, we just generate *N* nodes.

I still don't know if it is possible to iterate or not?

Comment: It is indeed possible. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29832938/509388

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use subworkflow option. Below is a rough idea you can develop on this.

....

```
 ....
<action name="someJava">
                <java>

                    <capture-output />
                </java>
                <ok to="counterCheck" />
                <error to="fail" />
    </action>


<decision name="counterCheck">
         <switch>
            <case to="continueFurther">
              ${wf:something == $counterVariable}
            </case>
            <default to="anotherAction" />
         </switch>
</decision>

<action name="continueFurther">
        <sub-workflow>
                <app-path>${repeatWorkflow}</app-path>
                <propagate-configuration/>
        </sub-workflow>
        <ok to="somejava"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
</action>
.....
.....
```

Comment: not sure how this would work.  Your workflow is not a DAG.  There is a loop in there, how does the subworkflow help?